# What is the lifecyle of a Webservice?

Tags: web-services, lifecycle

I was asked this in an interview and have not been able to find an answer. I do not know whether it refers to SOAP or REST, or whether it refers to the development or the execution lifecycle. Given this ambiguity, can you give answers for any of these possibilities?

Thank you and sorry for not being more specific.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really something I can straight up answer easily; you would be better reading this document to get the full understanding.

[Web Service Management: Service Life Cycle](http://www.w3.org/TR/wslc/)